# Where should a web application store dynamically generated content by default?

Tags: filesystems, webserver, web

Let's say you are developing a web application which generates reports based on user interaction. If you wanted to store those reports (*not* just temporarily cache them) somewhere in the *nix filesystem, where would be the most canonical default location?

My first instinct is `/var/application-name` or `/var/www/application-name`, similar to log files, since `/var` is for "variable" sized content, per [linux.com's description](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/linux-filesystem-explained/) of the filesystem.

However, `/srv/application-name` also seems appropriate, per the very same article's example of an FTP service.

It also seems appropriate to use `/usr/local/` or `/usr/share/`.

Comment: I would recomment not to save it on filesystem because your app won't scale. Save on filesystem only app files, ie. separate app from its data. Ideally save its data in distributed filesystem like S3 or in a DB. All this `/var` vs `/srv` location disputes are ridiculous. Especially today in time of containers. The main point of web app location should be mount options of underlying filesystem, ie. you don't want to have `suid`, `dev` option for the filesystem hosting your app files.

Comment: This question is specifically for "traditional" web applications, the type that are still developed around the world. In my case, the application is already containerized; however, we have customers who insist on a systemd-compatible deployment option, as they cannot run containers in their environment because of "reasons". Plus, in the end, you're eventually going to have to store the files in a filesystem somewhere, even if you're using containers with a backing store. The question isn't "should I?" it's "If I were, where would I?".

Comment: As most webservers have `/var/www` defined as *root* dir, you should then use it. For example on OpenBSD webservers chroot into `/var/www` for security reasons. But really think about moving `/var/www` (or any your desired location) to separate filesystem and give it secure mount options.

Comment: I feel it's also worth clarifying, for these comments anyway, that I am the developer of the application looking for a sane and canonical default location. In the end, I will not be maintaining the production version of the application. This location will be configurable by the end user, both though the application and by editing the Unit file itself.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is not to put your app files into root filesystem. Then the location really is up to you. Keep the filesystem hosting your app separate from any OS files, so you can always reinstall OS while keeping your app files intact.

Comment: All of the listed locations are off of the root filesystem, and are explicitly documented as being appropriate for service and/or user (system user, not "person" user) use.

Comment: For example a big German bank, I was doing sysadmin for, uses `/app/<app>`. If one knows why he does it this way, all possibilities are valid but one must know why he does it this way.